# Change the angle at which an object travels xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an object that travels on the screen and I was just wondering if there's any way that I could change the angle on which it travels.

I have this atm

```
enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos.x,enemy.center.y+pos.y);

    if (enemy.center.x > 328 || enemy.center.x < 0)
        pos.x = -pos.x;
    if (enemy.center.y > 480 || enemy.center.y < 0)
        pos.y = -pos.y;
```

Any ideas welcome and also is it possible to change the angle of which it bounces of the sides at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line equation is

```
y = tan(angle)*x + b.
```

Given an angle and the current position of the object you can find the next position:

Let's say your object is on `(6, 5)`, and you want it moving with a `45` degree angle.
`tan(45) = 1`. So you have `5 = 6 + b -> b = -1`. So the line the object should be moving on is 
`y = x - 1`.

So the next point could be `(7, 6)` or `(5, 4)` depending on the direction and amount of movement.

Comment: so how can i change the angel of travel?

Comment: If you find the tan(angle) and b for the point like I described above you can just use them to find out the new coords: obj_x = obj_x - 1(depending on direction) and obj_y = tan(angle)*obj_x + b

Comment: do you know were the angel is and or how to change it on this objects travel

Comment: you'll have to define it. It could be random, or you could calculate it depending on the point on the edge of the screen the enemy hits for example.

Comment: @BenWilson: think through what your code is doing - do it in English (or whatever native language) not code - say it out loud. Forget the math + code for a minute - just focus on the logic and the instructions. Just plugging in some code that somebody gives you is not going to help. Think STEPS - Up | Down |Left | Right. A steeper ANGLE means you move in BIGGER steps Up|Down than Left|Right.

Comment: iv done that and took bigger steps but this results in sometimes jumping out of a boundaries and disappearing :P

Comment: @BenWilson: again it's the logic NOT the code that is the issue. You are checking for < and > to flip the increment value AFTER you set your object's position. If the object was AT 0 (for example) then the next cycle, it will go out of bounds. A check for >= and <= should prevent this. Make sense?